# Hibernate generated id cause error message : "key already exists"

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using spring app with hibernate and postgres to store data. The configuration for the product entity is as follow :

```
/**
 * A Product.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    ...

}
```

When I want to create a product using the web app I get the following error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint. Detail : the key (id)=(35018) already exists`.

From my understanding hibernate use a sequence in db to generate the next id value. So I did `SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';` in the psql shell to get all sequence in my db. The output is :

```
hibernate_sequence
 jhi_user_id_seq
 key_value_id_seq
 jhi_persistent_audit_event_event_id_seq
 unit_id_seq
 generic_user_id_seq
 currency_id_seq
 customer_type_id_seq
 customer_exploitation_type_id_seq
 legal_entity_id_seq
 deposit_id_seq
 machine_id_seq
 tank_id_seq
 address_id_seq
 product_id_seq
 rewarded_file_id_seq
 bar_code_type_id_seq
 quality_label_id_seq
 shop_pdv_id_seq
 brand_id_seq
 category_id_seq
 material_id_seq
 ws_call_id_seq
 postal_code_id_seq
 commune_id_seq
 country_id_seq
 event_id_seq
 event_type_id_seq
 key_blob_id_seq
 card_id_seq
```

So I thought nice I have a product_id_seq and I only have to update the value in it for things to work.
But when I request the value with `SELECT * FROM product_id_seq;` I get :

```
 last_value | log_cnt | is_called
------------+---------+-----------
     100616 |       0 | t
```

So here I think that the id generated for the product id is not coming from this `product_id_sequence` since it tries to insert a product with id = `35018` and the `product_id_seq` last value is `100616`.

So I wonder where does this id 35018 comes from? Which sequence is used to generate it? My guess is I have to update this mysterious sequence to get things to work. For info the hibernate sequence has a value of `36400`.

Any idea that could get me going? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not map your sequence with postgre sequence so Hibernate creates the sequence `hibernate_sequence` (the one you got `35018` from) for itself.

To use your existing sequence:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator",  sequenceName = "product_id_seq")
private Long id;
```